# label changes if session exists

Tags: php, session

i'm building an website of sales and i need accounts for costumers and if the login is done

```
    session_start();
    include ("connbd.php"); where ligabd is the connection to the database
    $query = "SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE utilizador = '".$user."' AND pass = '".$pass."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($connbd,$query);
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if (!$result) {

    $_SESSION['user']=$user;
    $_SESSION['password']=$pass;
    header("location:index.php");
}
```

now in the index page i have the label login and register, my question is how with:

```
if isset $_SESSION['user']
label register="" & label login =""
labeluser=$_SESSION['user']
```

how do i solve this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can format source code with the [Code Sample `{}`](http://i.stack.imgur.com/VYd26.png) toolbar button—I've done it for you this time.

Comment: Hi
Are you asking how to make an if loop to see if they're set?

Comment: yes, but i dont know if it is possible to do it with php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
    session_start();

      if (isset $_SESSION['user']){
           $labelregister="";
           $labellogin ="";
           $labeluser=$_SESSION['user'];
      }
?>
```

Comment: how i change the values of the labels in the html after this?

Comment: in your html where the label is at you could do something like below to show the value in the label.
<label id='label1'><?php echo $labellogin; ?></label>

Answer (score 1):

put `session_start();` on first line of the code

[here is tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp)

enjoy :)

Comment: in the php post login?